# Fetch local JSON file using values from React Navigation route.params in React Native

Tags: reactjs, json, react-native, axios, fetch

I have a couple of local JSON files and i want to dynamically fetch them depending on values gotten from the route.params

When i use `import "../data/data.json"` it works, however route.params value aren't available then.

When i also use `const data = require("../data/data.json")` it works when the files directory is static whwn i try to make it dynamic it doesnt work. (I have read stackoverflow answers on why it doesn't).
What i want to know is how do i dynamically get my local .json files?

Some code snippet i have tried:

```
const data = require(`../Quizes/${cat}/${subcat}/data.json`)
```

where cat and subcat are route params

```
 axios.get(`../Quizes/${cat}/${subcat}/data.json`, {headers})
      .then(res => console.log(res))
      .catch(err => console.log(err.message));
      console.log(post)
    }, []);
```

With the above i get network error

I have also tried to use setTimeout to delay the `const data = require(`../Quizes/${cat}/${subcat}/data.json`)` so that the cat and subcat will be loaded first, still doesnt work.

Comment: If you are using create-react-app, then you need to add json to public folder. If it's in root of public folder then it can be accessed by "./some.json" in axios url.

Comment: I'm using react native

Answer (score 0):

You can pre-load all files into objects and then you just choose the correct

example:

```
import Cat1subCat1 from '../../data.json'
import Cat1subCat2 from '../../data.json'
import Cat2subCat1 from '../../data.json'
import Cat2subCat2 from '../../data.json'

function selectCategory(cat, subCat) {
 const categories = {
  cat1: { Cat1subCat1, Cat1subCat2 },
  cat2: { Cat2subCat1, Cat2subCat2 },
  // etc
 }

 return categories[cat][subCat]
}
```